# How to view full blocking postgres queries?

Tags: postgresql, logs, concurrency

I'm using a statement from [this page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) to view blocking queries in Postgres

```
SELECT bl.pid                 AS blocked_pid,
         a.usename              AS blocked_user,
         ka.query               AS blocking_statement,
         now() - ka.query_start AS blocking_duration,
         kl.pid                 AS blocking_pid,
         ka.usename             AS blocking_user,
         a.query                AS blocked_statement,
         now() - a.query_start  AS blocked_duration
  FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         bl
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a  ON a.pid = bl.pid
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         kl ON kl.transactionid = bl.transactionid AND kl.pid != bl.pid
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity ka ON ka.pid = kl.pid
  WHERE NOT bl.granted;
```

However the queries are truncated so I typically can't see what's in the `WHERE` clause which makes debugging these blocking issues very hard. Is there a setting where I can tell postgres to log the full queries to `pg_stat_activity`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The length of the query tracked can be found in the parameter `track_activity_query_size`.

[18.8.1. Query and Index Statistics Collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-statistics.html)

> ```
> track_activity_query_size (integer)
> ```
>
> Specifies the number of bytes reserved to track the currently executing command for each active session, for the
>   `pg_stat_activity.current_query` field. The default value is **1024**. This
>   parameter can only be set at server start.

e.g. if you had `track_activity_query_size=16384` in your config, then this would mean that query text up to 16k would be collected.

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear (as stated in the quote, which might go overlooked) .. changing that config option will require a server restart for it to take effect.